# How to create (and release) both a paid and lite version of an app using codename one

Tags: codenameone

I have seen answers to this question using other tools but I cannot see how to do it with CN1. If I release a LITE version of an app, what is the process for the user to get the PRO version once they have paid?

Like I said I have seen other answers but they talk about settings within the development studio itself which makes me think that it may be related to the toolset I am using - in this case Codename One.

Thanks.

P.S. I will need to know this for both Android and Apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for all the platform Codename One supports and is explained in [this tip](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deploy-same-mobile-app-template-multiple-times.html). Effectively you keep two or more `codenameone_settings.properties` and multiple Main packages/classes. Then toggle them by replacing the `codenameone_settings.properties` file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I love your product BTW  :-)